# Is there any way to switch on wifi in monkeyrunner otherthan using the cordinates

Tags: android, android-wifi, monkeyrunner, wifimanager

Is there any way to switch on wifi in monkeyrunner otherthan using the cordinates.?Can we use WifiManager api from monkeyrunner.

from android.net.wifi import WifiManger
 is working after copying android.jar file to tool/lib location.But how to invoke the WifiManger methods inside a android fon using monkeyrunner/monkey..??Somebody please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch on the wi-fi by another way. Start the activity of settings and go to the "wireless & network settings" and enable it.

Following code is the start the activity of the settings:

```
# sets a variable with the package's internal name
package = 'com.android.settings'

# sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the package
activity = 'com.android.settings.Settings'

# sets the name of the component to start
runComponent = package + '/' + activity

setting = 'com.android.settings.Settings'

print("")
print("")
print("Start the Activity...")

# Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)
```

After that by the press event use 'DOWN' and 'ENTER' KeyCode and you can enable the wi-fi...!!!

Comment: i can reach direclty to settings page by shell("monkey -p com.android.settings 1","","").. and DOWN UP works fine.But is there any method to know wthr WIFI is ON or OFF ??

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this exact issue a few months ago. It did not seem possible to me; at least easily. The best way I could find was to use startActivity to get as close to the wi-fi settings as possible, and then program in D-PAD commands until the correct field was highlighted. You may be able to use this logic to develop a small, purpose build, app that onCreate or onResume toggles wi-fi. In my case, it was not worth the amount of time this would have taken.

Comment: hi josh A,thanks for the reply.yea D-PAD commands works fine but in my case i want to connect to a scanned wifi network also,so its not possible to find out the position of scanned networks,it varies acc to the signal strength.so am not able to use DPAD for connecting.ANY IDEA??